# Getting "This method must be called with an app access_token" adding test users via graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create Facebook test accounts using the graph API. (I need to be able to log into them from my iphone app).  Here's how I'm getting the app access token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=MY-CLIENT-ID&client_secret=MY-CLIENT-SECRET
```

which seems to work fine.  And here's how I'm trying to create a user:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/MY-APP-ID/accounts/test-users?installed=true&name=TestUser1&permissions=read_stream&method=post&access_token=MY-APP-ACCESS-TOKEN
```

The response I'm getting is:

> This method must be called with an app access_token

I looked at this post [Problem with access token while creating Facebook Test Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485228/problem-with-access-token-while-creating-facebook-test-users).  Not really familiar with PHP, and just to make sure, I did try to "url encode" the app access token returned before using it... but no goodness.

I'm using Fiddler to test my posts.

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I found my problem -- "method=post" was the culprit.  I removed it and it worked.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't support test users for Native Mobile App

see related bug on bugzilla
http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=17779

hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Did you remove the 'access_token=' part from access token that's returned from the first request? If not, then you'll have an incorrect request on the second call, since the URL will have 'access_token=' twice.